# PyQGIS: QgsVectorFileWriter.create() doesn't flush even after deleted

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

If `QgsVectorFileWriter` constructor is directly used, the output is flushed when the reference is deleted.  I'm trying to switch to `QgsVectorFileWriter.create()` because QGIS warns that the former is being deprecated.  But as far as I tested, `QgsVectorFileWriter.create()` does not flush the output until `QgsApplication.exitQgis()` is called.

I'm not familiar with Python, QGIS, and C++.  I see that `QgsVectorFileWriterTask` does something asynchronous, but I'm so weak to follow the code.

QGIS version: 3.10.3
OS: macOS 10.15.3

Answer (score 7):

`QgsVectorFileWriter.create()` does not flush the output until `QgsApplication.exitQgis()` is called, because `create()` method uses `QgsVectorFileWriter` constructor method behind the scenes.Since it's deleted while exiting QGIS, it flushes the output.

Use newly added [`writeAsVectorFormatV2`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#a3ce5d9e1ceeda1dcf3ccefb0c97f1941) method.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
file_path = "/Path/To/File.shp"

options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = "ESRI Shapefile"

QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(layer, file_path, QgsCoordinateTransformContext(), options)
```

Comment: I'm not sure 100% about *"Since it's deleted while exiting QGIS, it flushes the output"*, but it must be.

Comment: I know that `writeAsVectorFormatV2` works.  I need `QgsVectorFileWriter` constructor because features are incrementally added (`addFeature()`) in this particular case.

I see that `create()` method is not tested in [1].

[1] QGIS/tests/src/python/test_qgsvectorfilewriter.py

Comment: I've already noticed that. I'm looking for the solution, too. Could it be a bug?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a bug that might be fixed in next release (3.16):
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/37629

You can work around it by creating the file with QgsVectorFileWriter and then open the file and add the attributes and features again, somewhat like:

```
fields = src_layer.fields()

layer = iface.addVectorLayer(layer_path, layer_name , "ogr")
pr = layer.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes(fields)
layer.updateFields()

fs = []
for src_f in src_layer.getFeatures():
    f = QgsFeature(src_f)
    f.setAttributes(src_f.attributes())
    f.setGeometry(some_kind_of_geom)
    fs.append(f)

pr.addFeatures(fs)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but just had the same effect with QGis 3.24.1

I used

```
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.create(...)
```

tried to add the new created (empty) gpkg-layer to the project with

```
iface.addVectorLayer(...)
```

but got an "Invalid Data Source" Error

After using

```
del writer
```

**before** loading the layer everything was OK.

Delete of the writer-reference seems to flush the layer from ram to disk, QgsApplication.exitQgis() is not necessary.